# Not getting my data to my angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I am reading in a data.json file and I am trying to populate the tabs using this. I was able to do it without the use of a custom directive but, I want to create multiple possibilities of layouts using directives. I cannot however get my ng-repeat to function within the templates/directives/tabs.html file. Here is my set up. Also, my $scope.data.data takes me to an array that again I was able to successfully loop through. Is the scope within a directive a different drill down than in the index.html?

index.html the drill down is the following {{data.whatever}}
Is it the same inside the directive?

```
.controller('TabController', function($scope, $http, _){
    $scope.model = {};
    $http.get('data.json').then(function(resp) {
    $scope.data = resp.data.data;
})

angular.module('myApp').directive('cmTabs', function() {
    return { 
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            content: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/directives/tabs.html'
    };
})
```

});

My markup is as such

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabController">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>{{data.PageTitle}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><!-- <img alt="Brand" src="..."> -->{{data.PageTitle}}</a>
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li ng-class='{active:$first}' ng-repeat="menu in data.toplevelcontainer" ng-click="model.activeTab=tab" tooltip="{{menu.label}}" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="bottom">
                   <a href="#">{{menu.label}}</a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid" ng-if="data.Layout === 'tabs'" >
          <div cm-tabs content="data"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid" ng-if="data.Layout === 'menu'">
          <h1>menu</h1>
        </div>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("ul.nav-tabs a").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();  
                $(this).tab('show');
            });</script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

DIRECTIVE Template

```
<div class="tabbable boxed parentTabs">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="set1">
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-repeat="t in data.toplevelcontainer">
                    <li ng-class='{active:$first}' ng-repeat="st in t.content.innercontent" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="{{st.tooltip}}"><a href="#{{st.label}}">{{sub_tab.label}}</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using ng-controller in your markup?

Comment: I am indeed. <html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TabController">

Comment: Can you post more of your markup, specifically how `content` is being bound?

Comment: Might just be a typo in your question code but your controller function is not complete. You're missing `})`

Comment: Hi Phil, yes it is a typo I'll add to post

Comment: @pcproff Hi, how does your directive template look like? I mean how do you use your `content` model inside your directive's template?

Comment: @AbhilashPA I have posted this. I wonder if I should use content.toplevelcontainer?

Comment: @pcproff, yes, you should use `content` instead of `data`.

Comment: @AbhilashPA such an oversight !!! But now, I know how directives receive data. Now to read docs on what '=' means

Comment: @pcproff, can I get a `accepted answer` if I post this comment as my Answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `content.toplevelcontainer` instead of `data.toplevelcontainer`.

Because you are mapping your controller's scope model `data` into `content` in your directive. So, the data from your controller is now assigned to your directive's scope variable `content`.

So, your `ng-repeat` should be look like this,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-repeat="t in content.toplevelcontainer">
```

Comment: Your exactly right! That's what I did! Thanks again.